# Facebook events editable only through my android app

Tags: android, facebook, events

Is there any specific permission to make my facebook events editable only through the app that created it?
So far for testing i have set the type of event "OPEN"

Answer (score 0):

From what I read in the facebook developer page we can't do that for further reference please read -> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/

Comment: I don;t know bit if I cant restrict the editing i would use another architecture. The real reason i want the users not be able to edit the event manually (on the webpage) is that i want the address to have a specific format and then i use string parsing to mine the exact data in my android app (specifically coordinates of an event). Otherwise the event cannot be proccessed in my application

Comment: The address...where are you storing the address in the format you are parsing, in the description? Can't you use the address returned by the Graph API call?

Comment: No here is the thing. Since the facebook places api has problems with geocoding i use the google api geocoder and have an address published on the facebook like this format "Ermou 23, Volos 37.6720276;21.4402223". Then I am parsing this address to get lat and lon. If someone for every reason goes on the facebook web page and change the location to something like "Ermou 23, Volos-Greece" I would not be able to parse this string to get lat and lon. Otherwise i would have to use an external database to store latitude and longitude of a location.